# Issue with Aurelia class.bind with checked.bind

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to use `class.bind` in a way that makes it dependent on `checked.bind`.

My use case is pretty simple. I have a list of items, displayed using a `table`. Each row of this table has a `checkbox`. I want to mark a row as "selected" whenever the corresponding `checkbox` (of the row) is checked.
For this I have used following binding:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="item of items" class.bind="$parent.selectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1?'info':''">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked.bind="$parent.selectedItems" model.bind="item" />
        </td>
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, the same doesn't work as intended, and this can be seen in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mvTSa?p=preview).

As a workaround I used a `getter` with `@computedFrom('selectedItems', 'items')` and/or `declarePropertyDependencies(App, 'classes', ['selectedItems', 'items']);`  , as follows:

```
import {computedFrom, declarePropertyDependencies} from "aurelia-framework";

export class App {
   ...

    @computedFrom('selectedItems', 'items')
    get classes() {
        const self = this;
        const retval= self.items.map((item: any) => {
            return self.selectedItems.indexOf(item) > -1 ? "info" : "";
        });

        return retval;
    }
}

//declarePropertyDependencies(App, 'classes', ['selectedItems', 'items']);
```

However, this too does not work as can be seen here in this [workaround plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ly0bQn?p=preview).

It only works, if none of `@computedFrom` and/or `declarePropertyDependencies` is used, and that obviously involves dirty-checking.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding system will reevaluate the class binding expression `class.bind="$parent.selectedItems.indexOf(item)>-1?'info':''"` anytime a property used in the expression changes. The `selectedItems` property never changes, it remains the same array instance. Understandably this is a little confusing because the array instance is mutating.  Here's a workaround you can use: add selectedItems.length to the binding expression... we know it will change when items are pushed/popped from the array.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=09d32941842352ff0025**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <p>${message}</p>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr repeat.for="item of items" class.bind="selectedItems.length === 0 || selectedItems.indexOf(item) === -1 ? '' : 'info'">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" checked.bind="selectedItems" model.bind="item" />
        </td>
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ${selectedItems.length} items selected
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  constructor(router) {
    this.message = "Hello World!";
    this.items = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "A"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "B"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "C"
    }];
    this.selectedItems=[];
  }
}
```